# Is cutting through hole leads done by hand or machine when wave soldering?

Tags: automation, through-hole

If machines exist, can someone provide some info on what to look for. I'm aware of the frames for doing it by hand. I'm curious how to keep the parts in place once the leads are cut, ie don't shake the board or parts might be displaced.

Comment: Actually the terminal are cutted (and clinched!) during insertion so the wave can work at its best. So you are looking for a THT inserter

Comment: That seems more like what i had in mind. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, machines exist to trim the leads. They have a big carbide circular blade.

(photo from eBay):

[image]

Comment: Follow up question: Is this always completed as post processing? From what I've seen that is how theses machines are being used.

Comment: That’s the only way I’ve seen them used. Might not be acceptable for high reliability applications.